# Are dictionaries and other generics bad DTOs?

Tags: servicestack, dto

Do generic types such as `IDictionary` and `IEnumerable` really bad for DTOs?  They seems to be serialized and deserialized ok by ServiceStack, but RestSharp is having problems with them.

I understand once they get JSON `stringified` they just look like lists and dictionaries, but should I be making specific DTOs?

Here is an example I have pairs of (`Int`, `String`) and RestSharp is having problems with the int because the JSON serializer puts quotes around the int.

I have been searching around a bit and could use some good guidelines on what makes a safe DTO.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is quite normal. JSON requires that all keys are quoted-string literals, see http://json.org.

Comment: Ah that had me confused because i know I have seen "Soemthing":2 where the int is not quoted